# Vue.js typescript interface not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Does anyone know what's the syntaxt to create a type for data properties in vue.js (application is being written in typescript)?
I'm looking for something like:

```ts
@Component({
  data() {
    return {
      sections: Array<SomeInterface> = []
    }
  }
})
```

But vue sees a type as a value and I'm confused how to approach it.

Comment: You should use cass-style components. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components

Comment: I actually used your suggestion, if you write it as an anwser I mark it as a correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [class-style components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Component%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs) using `vue-class-component`, which allow you to move these declarations to class properties and plays well with Typescript.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

// The @Component decorator indicates the class is a Vue component
@Component({
  // All component options are allowed in here
  template: '<button @click="onClick">Click!</button>'
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  // Initial data can be declared as instance properties
  message: string = 'Hello!'

  // Component methods can be declared as instance methods
  onClick (): void {
    window.alert(this.message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `:` as you normally would to precede the type because the syntax conflicts with JavaScript's `key: value` object literal syntax. You can just use type inference instead by forcing the empty array `[]` to the `SomeInterface[]` type:

```ts
@Component({
  data() {
    return {
      sections: [] as SomeInterface[]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: You should consider explaining your answer in more depth.  It was labeled as "low quality" because it is mostly code.

Comment: I figured it was too trivial to explain in detail when compared to OP's code. Updated.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in this kind of component, but it turns out I should use different syntax, thank you very much!
+1